# Pipelining Multiple unwinds in an Mongo aggeregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have an interesting use case that I am working against which would require me to apply Mongo's $unwind operator on two array types (which is an attribute in the mongo document)

Heres an example where I'd wish to filter on 2 enum types 
$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun - enum("ssd","disk1","disk2")
$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block - range(1000-100000)

Can I $unwind multiple operators and filter upon them in a single aggregation pipeline

```
               db["XXXXXXX"].aggregate( { $unwind : { "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun", "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block" } }, 
                               { $match : { "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.lunType" : "cdrom"  , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block" : { $gte : 60000 } , "managedObject" : "host" } } , 
                               { $project : { "host.name" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.devicePath" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.ssd" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.uuid" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.lunType" : 1 , "_id" : 0  }} )
```

OR

Can I chain a composite aggregation operational unit's result to another aggregation unit

```
               db["XXXXXXX"].aggregate( { $unwind : "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun" }, 
               { $match : { "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.lunType" : "cdrom"  , "managedObject" : "host" } } , 
               { $project : { "host.name" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.devicePath" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.ssd" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.uuid" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.lunType" : 1 , "_id" : 0  }},
               { $unwind : "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" },
               { $match : { "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" : { $gte : 8000000 } } },
               { $project : { "host.name" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.devicePath" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.ssd" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.uuid" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.lunType" : 1 , "_id" : 0  }}
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question: Mongo aggregate accept double $unwind stages to create a cartesian product. Both of your propositions look good to me (of course I did not check word by word). Try and if does not work, come back.

Comment: I tried the first one and it does not work !

Can I have multiple attributed unwinded i.e. is this syntax valid



        $unwind : { "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun", "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block" } ...

Comment: I am not not sure if you can put them directly togheter. For the double unwind, you need two different stages like: db.somthing.aggregate([{$unwind: "$firstArrayKey"}, {$unwind: "$secondArayKey"}, other stages of the pipeline ]); This way you get a cartesian product. Let say you have a collection of pants, each doc of the form {pant_name:"the name", colors: [array of available colors], size: [array of available size]} the double unwind will give you a document for each single color and single size.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion .. Will circle back with you after I try it out... Thanks again

Comment: Another question :

Does one have to chain the pipelines in a specified format, like
$unwind->$match->$project->$unwind->$match->$project
or
can I apply a double unwind in tandem like this
$unwind->$unwind->$match->$project

Comment: The order does not matter.

Comment: Did not work
db["XXXX"].aggregate( { $unwind : "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun" },{ $unwind : "$host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" }, { $match : { "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.lunType" : "cdrom"  ,"managedObject" : "host" ,"host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" : { $gte : 100 } } } , { $project : { "host.name" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.devicePath" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.blockSize" : 1 , "host.config.storageDevice.scsiLun.capacity.block" : 1 , "_id" : 0  }})

Comment: I imagine host is a subdoc of the main doc, config a subdoc of host, storageDevice a subdoc of config and scliLun an array field of storageDevice. Can you show sample documents of your collection? Also, you should test the pipeline stage by stage, not putting all the stage at once. for example, start with one stage, limit the result to 1 or 2, and print to see if it looks like what you expected.